# JTextField is initialised but appears to be null

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I do not understand what is happening in my code, when I fire a button with attached action listener,  reading the JTextField getText() value shows as null, even though all fields contain text. Furthermore when I debugged the code and stopped just before this line the JTextField object showed as null as well, like it was never initialised in the first place.

I'm not sure whether I can keep all these JLabel and JTextField as class members and then just freely read from them.

```
public class EditPartGUI extends JFrame {
    private JLabel manufacturerLabel;
    private JTextField manufacturerTextField;

    private JButton submit;
    private ActionListener submitListener;

    public EditPartGUI(Part part) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(initialiseField("Manufacturer: ", manufacturerLabel, part.getManufacturer(), manufacturerTextField));

        JPanel sub = new JPanel();
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submitListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(submit().toString());
            }
        };
        submit.addActionListener(submitListener);

        sub.add(submit);
        panel.add(sub);

        this.add(panel);
    }

    public JPanel initialiseField(String label, JLabel contentLabel, String value, JTextField contentTextField) {
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentLabel = new JLabel(label, JLabel.TRAILING);

        contentTextField = new JTextField(10);
        contentTextField.setText(value);
        contentLabel.setLabelFor(contentTextField);

        contentPanel.add(contentLabel);
        contentPanel.add(contentTextField);
        return contentPanel;
    }

    public Part submit() {
        Part p = new Part();
        p.setManufacturer(this.manufacturerTextField.getText()); // <---- this is where NullPointerException shows
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is pass by value, not pass by reference.  Passing the value of `manufacturerTextField` to a method can't possibly initialise it.

Comment: @DavidWallace is this not a valid way to initialise that field? I wrote a separate method to do that (initialiseField()), so I could avoid repeating the same code for each field (there are a lot more of them in my actual code).

Comment: You didn't initialise the field.  You passed `null` into a method, which created a new field, but didn't assign it to `manufacturerTextField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether I can keep all these JLabel and JTextField as class members and then just freely read from them.

Yes you can and that is the solution to your problem.

Just use the following when you

```
//private JTextField manufacturerTextField;
private JTextField manufacturerTextField = new JTextField();
```

and don't try to create the text field in your initialiseField() method. Of course you will need to do the same with the label.

> so I could avoid repeating the same code for each field (there are a lot more of them in my actual code).

If you want to have many panels with those fields, then you need to create a custom class to create the panel and then the text fields and labels will be part of that class, not your main class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you assume that the method initialiseField is assigning the argument contentTextField to manufactererTextField. This won't work in Java as David Wallace already stated.

If you want to avoid repeating the same code, try to create a method that returns the initialised TextField and assign it in the constructor.